# Installing msttcorefonts on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, installation, fonts, linux-mint

I am trying to get Times New Roman on LibreOffice. I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install msttcorefonts
```

I think it downloaded, but it doesn't appear in the OpenOffice drop down list of fonts.

Comment: Can you see them in the output of `fc-list |grep Times`?

Answer (score 1):

The package contents of msttcorefonts belong here,

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/
```

So, just do

```
sudo fc-cache -f /usr/share/fonts/truetype/
```

If unsuccessful, then the package did not in fact install to completion. In that case, install again as root and report back the exact output.

To explain, if you're unsure about the -f flag of fc-cache, this comes is from the fc-cache [man page](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=fc-cache)

```
 -f     Force re-generation of apparently up-to-date cache files, overriding the timestamp checking.
```